# How do I exclude certain junit tests when running 'mvn test'

Tags: spring-boot, maven, junit

I've got this JUnit Test

```
@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("/features")
@SelectClasspathResource("/generated")
class NightlyTest {

}
```

When I run `mvn test` it runs all the cucumber tests in `/features` and `/generated`

There are thousands of cucumber tests under `/generated` and they take hours to run. In our pipeline I want to have control over if generated tests are included or not.

How can I only run specific tests based on a mvn command or environment variable?

eg. something like
`mvn test -ExcludeGeneratedTests` would be perfect

If I add `@ExcludeTags("generated")` to the class, it will exclude all tests I've tagged with @generated, which is exactly what I want, except I don't know how to turn that on and off from the mvn command the pipeline uses.

I've tried setting a environment variable, `EXCLUDE_TAGS=generated` and changing the annotation to `@ExcludeTags("${EXCLUDE_TAGS}")` but it doesn't work. I've also tried MANY other simular solutions but neither seem to work.

how can I include/exclude generated tests from a mvn command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Maven to include and exclude groups of tests. For example:

```
mvn verify -DexcludedGroups="Ignore" -Dgroups="Smoke | Sanity"
```

This will run any tests tagged with Smoke or Sanity, but of those none that are also tagged with Ignore.

The values for these properties are [JUnit 5 Tag expressions](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-tag-expressions) which [Surefire will pass to the JUnit Platform](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#excludedGroups) which [passes them to Cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine).

Comment: Thanks! I wasted so much time trying to use 
-Dcucumber.filter.tags to filter test, but this method worked! Wish cucumber would stop changing so much between version OR have better doc around that

Comment: Guess you didn't read: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm#upgrading